# make UI.sortable work with cookie plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have actually found a snippet which works for one user, but however when I try to apply the code to my page, I can sort the elements but it never saves what I have sorted. Please tell me what is wrong with this code.

(I copied from another question, not mine)

```
var setSelector = "#sortable";
// set the cookie name
var setCookieName = "listOrder";
// set the cookie expiry time (days):
var setCookieExpiry = 7;

// function that writes the list order to a cookie
function getOrder() {
        // save custom order to cookie
        $.cookie(setCookieName, $(setSelector).sortable("toArray"), { expires: setCookieExpiry, path: "/" });
}

// function that restores the list order from a cookie
function restoreOrder() {
        var list = $(setSelector);
        if (list == null) return

        // fetch the cookie value (saved order)
        var cookie = $.cookie(setCookieName);
        if (!cookie) return;

        // make array from saved order
        var IDs = cookie.split(",");

        // fetch current order
        var items = list.sortable("toArray");

        // make array from current order
        var rebuild = new Array();
        for ( var v=0, len=items.length; v<len; v++ ){
                rebuild[items[v]] = items[v];
        }

        for (var i = 0, n = IDs.length; i < n; i++) {

                // item id from saved order
                var itemID = IDs[i];

                if (itemID in rebuild) {

                        // select item id from current order
                        var item = rebuild[itemID];

                        // select the item according to current order
                        var child = $("ul" + setSelector + ".ui-sortable").children("#" + item);

                        // select the item according to the saved order
                        var savedOrd = $("ul" + setSelector + ".ui-sortable").children("#" + itemID);

                        // remove all the items
                        child.remove();

                        // add the items in turn according to saved order
                        // we need to filter here since the "ui-sortable"
                        // class is applied to all ul elements and we
                        // only want the very first!  You can modify this
                        // to support multiple lists - not tested!
                        $("ul" + setSelector + ".ui-sortable").filter(":first").append(savedOrd);

                }
        }
}

        // here, we allow the user to sort the items
        $(setSelector).sortable({
                cursor: 'move',
                items: 'li',
                //axis: "y",
                opacity: 0.6,
                //revert: true,
                scroll: true,
                scrollSensitivity: 40,
                placeholder: 'highlight',
                update: function() { getOrder(); }
        });

        // here, we reload the saved order
        restoreOrder();
```

It just does not save, i can sort and everything. this is my markup. i try to keep everything simple for test purpose.

```
<ul id="sortable">
 <li>test 1</li>
 <li>test 2</li>
</ul>
```

Please can you correct this code to make it save cookie and reload the saved settings when I refresh. I am so desperate for this one :))

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to put ID to each `<li>`

for example:

```
   <ul id="sortable">
 <li id="item-1">test 1</li>
 <li id="item-2">test 2</li>
   </ul>
```

Also, make sure you close your code at the end with `});`